# Repository Behind Remote on Some Files Ahead on Others

Tags: git

Let's say my repository looks like this:

```
repo/
    file1
    file2
```

The version on `file1` is ahead of my remote repository on github, but the version of `file2` is behind. I don't want to push because then the remote version of `file2` will be messed up, but I can't pull because I get merge conflicts on `file1`. How does one solve this problem most efficiently?

I would ideally like to just push my local `file1` to get the remote repository up to speed then pull the whole thing back and clobber `file2` with the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to do it manually. You could `cp file1` to a temporary file. Then you can safely pull the whole repo and replace `file1` even though it is newer than the remote. Then I'd just `mv file1` from the temp folder back in and then commit that replacement to the remote repository:

```
$git add file1.ext
$git commit -m "updated file1/what you want to call it"
$git push origin master
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes this is basically what I did, I just cloned the repo in another directory and copied over the ahead files then committed.. no quicker way to ruin your night then merge conflicts..

Comment: yah, well I hope your repo is properly updated and in the end no harm was done.